# Making at least one of many parameters required in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameters, optional-parameters, powershell-5.1

In PowerShell, I want to write a function, that accepts different options as parameters. It is OK, if it receives *more than one* parameter, but it has to receive *at least one* parameter. I want to enforce it through the parameter definition and not through code afterwards. I can get it to work with the following code:

```
function Set-Option {

    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption1")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption2")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption3")]
        $Option1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption1")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption2")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption3")]
        $Option2,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption1")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption2")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName="AtLeastOption3")]
        $Option3
    )

    # Do stuff, but don't evaluate the plausibility of the given parameters here
}
```

But as you can see, it scales badly. For each additional option, I have to add a line to all other options. Can this be done in a more efficient and a more maintainable way?

As I already said, I don't want to check the parameters in the code, e. g. through evaluating `$PSBoundParameters`. I want it to happen in the parameter definition for auto-doc reasons.

---

If you need a real world example, have a look at [`Set-DhcpServerv4OptionValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dhcpserver/set-dhcpserverv4optionvalue) which accepts many different options (`-DnsDomain`, `-DnsServer`, `-Router`, ...), where it is OK to have them all, but it makes no sense to have none.

---

*Note*: After several answers have already been provided, I just realized that my code is actually *not* working, if you provide more than one option.

Comment: Are you referring to wanting a *Default Parameter Set Name*? `[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName="AtLeastOption1")]`

Comment: At some point on your function body there should be a validation on which parameters were bounded I would assume, it would be nice to see a different alternative!

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That would enforce parameter set `AtLeastOption1` in this case. You would always have to provide `Option1` even if you have provided another option.

Comment: So, the answer to my question is no. lol got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following isn't a great solution - and depending on what you mean by *auto-doc*, it may not work for you -  but it scales well, as you'll only ever need *one* additional parameter set:

```
function Set-Option {

  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Fail')]
  Param(
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AtLeastOne')]
      $Option1,

      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AtLeastOne')]
      $Option2,

      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AtLeastOne')]
      $Option3,

      # Declare a dummy parameter whose default value throws an error
      # if no other parameter is passed.
      # Note: All that 'DontShow' does is to exclude the parameter
      #       from tab completion; doesn't hide it from syntax diagram.
      [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Fail', DontShow)] 
      ${-} = $(
        if ($PScmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Fail') { 
          throw "Please specify at least one option." 
        }
      )
  )

  # Do stuff, without needing to evaluate the plausibility of
  # the given parameters here.

}
```

- All real parameters are *optional* and belong to the same parameter set that is *not* the default.
- The purpose of dummy parameter `${-}`, which is the only one in the default parameter set, is solely to throw an error via its *default* value.

  - Since the default value is *always* evaluated, a conditional is needed to throw only if the default parameter set has been selected (`$PScmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Fail'`).
  - Due to the parameter's irregular name, you actually cannot pass an explicit value to it (which is desirable here, because it is purely auxiliary and not meant for direct use): you'd have to use `-- <value>`, but `--` has special meaning to the parameter binder (deactivates named parameter binding for the subsequent arguments).
  - Unfortunately, property `DontShow` (e.g. `[Parameter(DontShow)]`) only hides the parameter from *tab-completion*, not also from the *syntax diagrams*.

    - [GitHub issue #7868](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7868) proposes introducing a way to hide (obsolete) parameters from the syntax diagram.

Thus, unfortunately, the dummy parameter set and its parameter appear in the syntax diagram, so that `Set-Option -?` shows the following:

```
SYNTAX
    Set-Option [-- <Object>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-Option [-Option1 <Object>] [-Option2 <Object>] [-Option3 <Object>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Note that syntax diagrams lack a notation for your desired logic.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As OP noted, the solution presented here **doesn't work when more than one argument** is passed:

```text
Set-Option -Option1 foo -Option2 42

Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more    
parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were
provided.
```

I'll keep it as an example for using `DynamicParam`.

---

This is a solution using [`DynamicParam`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#dynamic-parameters) to automatically generate the same parameter sets that you have created manually. Despite not being a "code-free" solution, it still shows the expected syntax diagram (when called like `Set-Option -?`), because PowerShell gets all necessary information from the `DynamicParam` block.

First we define a reusable helper function to be able to write a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) `DynamicParam` block:

```
Function Add-ParamGroupAtLeastOne {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Define a group of parameters from which at least one must be passed.
    #>
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary] $Params,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] [Collections.Specialized.IOrderedDictionary] $ParamDefinitions
    )

    foreach( $paramDef in $ParamDefinitions.GetEnumerator() ) {

        $attributes = [Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Attribute]]::new()

        # Generate parameter sets for one parameter
        foreach( $groupItem in $ParamDefinitions.Keys ) {
            $attr = [Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
                Mandatory = $paramDef.Key -eq $groupItem
                ParameterSetName = "AtLeastOne$groupItem"
            }
            if( $paramDef.Value.HelpMessage ) {
                $attr.HelpMessage = $paramDef.Value.HelpMessage
            }
            
            $attributes.Add( $attr )
        }
    
        # Add one parameter
        $Params.Add( $paramDef.Key, [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new( $paramDef.Key, $paramDef.Value.Type, $attributes ))         
    }
}
```

The `Set-Option` function can now be written like this:

```
Function Set-Option {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()  # Still required

    DynamicParam {
        $parameters = [Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()

        Add-ParamGroupAtLeastOne -Params $parameters -ParamDefinitions ([ordered] @{ 
            Option1 = @{ Type = 'string'; HelpMessage = 'the 1st option' }
            Option2 = @{ Type = 'int';    HelpMessage = 'the 2nd option' }
            Option3 = @{ Type = 'bool';   HelpMessage = 'the 3rd option' }
        })

        $parameters
    }    

    process {
        # Do stuff
    }
}
```

`Set-Option -?` outputs this syntax diagram, as expected:

```text
SYNTAX
    Set-Option -Option1 <string> [-Option2 <int>] [-Option3 <bool>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-Option -Option2 <int> [-Option1 <string>] [-Option3 <bool>] [<CommonParameters>]

    Set-Option -Option3 <bool> [-Option1 <string>] [-Option2 <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

If you want to add more parameter attributes, have a look at the [`ParameterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.parameterattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#properties) class and add the desired attributes in the function `Add-ParamGroupAtLeastOne` as I have done exemplary for `HelpMessage`.

Comment: I just realized that my code is actually _not_ working, if you provide more than one option. Unfortunately, the same applies to your solution.

Comment: @stackprotector That's unfortunate! The error looks like as if PowerShell can't resolve the arguments to a single parameter set. You get the same message (as expected) when calling this function with both arguments: `function fun{ param( [parameter(parametersetname='x')] $x, [parameter(parametersetname='y')] $y ) }`

Comment: As for why it doesn't work: To resolve ambiguity, a default parameter set must be designated. However, since all parameter sets have at least one mandatory parameter, choosing any one of them as the default would invariably prompt for its respective mandatory parameter, if not specified; e.g., if you make the one with `-Option1` the default parameter set and try to call `Set-Option -Option 2`, you'll get a prompt for the value of `-Option 1`.

Comment: Yikes that's a big limitation for Parameter Sets in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters are all switches (i.e., you specify them as `-Option1` rather than `-Option1 SomeValue`), include a test at the beginning of the actual code that checks that they're not ALL false, and if they are, reject the invocation. If they're value parameters (i.e., `-Option1 SomeValue`), you'll have to test each of them against `$null`, and if they're all `$null`, reject the invocation.

```
function Set-Option {
   param (
      [switch]$Option1,
      [switch]$Option2,
      ...
   )

   if (!($Option1 -or $Option2 -or ...)) {
      # reject the invocation and abort
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, but they are not switches and I am not looking for a solution in the code section.